# how to add routing OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3

i have following link html how to add Routing(longitude latitude)A To B location, i am using OpenLayers 3 any idea? Please help.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/feature-move-animation.html

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/examples/wmts-hidpi.html

Comment: Do you mean car routing?

Comment: YES Pickup and destination

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/) if helps.

Comment: where id enter logitude, latitude

Comment: I am from pakistan enter these cordinates nothing show result var points = [];
points[0] = 53.793881,-1.749792;
points[1] = 53.796661,-1.751172';

Comment: You'll need to get your start and end coords and make a call to a routing service like one of these: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers.
Check out their APIs for how to construct a request, then they should send back a list of coord steps you can use to draw a line.